# Why Select2 change event fires form submit?

Tags: jquery, forms, submit, jquery-select2

I have a tagging system build with [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) where users should be able to select existing tags or add new tags. Simplified version of my code looks like this:

```
$('input').select2({
    tags: [
        {id:0, text:'red', status:'old'},
        {id:1, text:'green', status:'old'},
        {id:2, text:'blue', status:'old'}
    ],
    tokenSeparators: [","],
    createSearchChoice: function (term, data) {
        return {id: term, text: term, status: 'new'};
    }
}).change(function(e) {
    if (e.added && e.added.status == 'new') {
        if (confirm('Not found. Add?')) {
            // Add new tag to database.
        }
    }
});
```

Here is example ([example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/Xmbym/6/)) how it should work. (User can add existing tags "red", "green" and "blue". createSearchChoice-function allows users to create new tags.) In this example, nothing is done in .change() -event when new tag is detected. Everything works as expected.

However, like in code block above, when new tag is added I'd like to confirm user if he/she really want to add new tag. The problem is when I add confirmation code in brackets where new tag is detected, form submit event fires. Here is example ([example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Xmbym/7/)) of this behavior. Just try to add tag that doesn't exist.

Now my questions are:

1. Why form submit occurs?
2. How could I prevent this behavior?

I'm using select2 3.4.0 and jQuery 2.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One explanation is that when confirm-function stops execution of change-event, browser continues it's job and runs form submit handler that fired when user pressed enter while selecting new tag. Normally select2 prevents this execution, but in this case it's blocked by confirm-function.

Now if confirmation logic is moved to it's own separate function and is called from setTimeout-function, change-event executes normally and select2 prevents form submit.

```
$('input').select2({
    tags: [
        {id:0, text:'red', status:'old'},
        {id:1, text:'green', status:'old'},
        {id:2, text:'blue', status:'old'}
    ],
    tokenSeparators: [","],
    createSearchChoice: function (term, data) {
       return {id: term, text: term, status: 'new'};
    }
}).change(function(e) {
    if (e.added && e.added.status == 'new') {
        setTimeout(myConfirm,50);
    }
});

function myConfirm() {
    if (confirm('Not found. Add?')) {
        // Add new tag to database.
    }
}
```

Here is a [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Xmbym/8/) of this solution.

Other explanations and solutions are still highly appreciated!